# String declaration in java

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between these two string declarations?

```
String s1 = "tis is sample";
String s2 = new String ("tis is sample");
```

When I check `s1==s2` it says `false`.

Why is it `false`?

Could you also explain the working behind these two declarations. I am so confused with it. Which one should I use to declare a `String`?

Comment: You should try searching existing questions first, there are many same answered questions.

Comment: Actually it appears to be a nested duplicate because that one was also marked duplicate

Comment: And try to write proper words with nice punctuation and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

While string comparison, you have to use

```
if ( s1.equals(s2) ) {
  do something; 
}
```

not use `==`

```
// These two have the same value
s1.equals(s2) // --> true 

// ... but they are not the same object
s1 == s2 // --> false 

// ... neither are these
new String("test") == new String("test") // --> false 

// ... but these are because literals are interned by 
// the compiler and thus refer to the same object
"tis is sample" == "tis is sample" // --> true 

// ... but you should really just call Objects.equals()
Objects.equals(s1, new String("tis is sample")) // --> true
Objects.equals(null, "tis is sample") // --> false
```

In addition you can check details from below code http://rextester.com/GUR44534